# Duplicated videos with my php+jquery app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, video

im having a problem with my php code (http://pastebin.com/ZJaHsupF). Im trying to show some videos in to the html with a javascript function for change one by one when they finish. But the browser show me the video[1] and videos[2] duplicated. I have 5 videos in the directory. 
My jquery function:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'> </script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.index_0')[0].play();
        $('video').bind('ended', function(){
            $( this ).hide();
            $( this ).next(this).show();
            $( this ).next(this)[0].play();
        });
  });
</script>

<style type='text/css'>
    .index_1 {
        display: none;
    }
    #centrar {
        top:50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: 150px;
    }
</style>

<div id='centrar' align='center' >
    <video id='myVideo' class='index_0' width='70%'' muted autoplay> 
    <source src='publicidad/video1.webm' type='video/webm'/></video>

    <video id='myVideo' class='index_1' width='70%'' muted autoplay> 
    <source src='publicidad/video2.webm' type='video/webm'/></video>

    <video id='myVideo' class='index_1' width='70%'' muted autoplay> 
    <source src='publicidad/video3.webm' type='video/webm'/></video>

    <video id='myVideo' class='index_1' width='70%'' muted autoplay> 
    <source src='publicidad/video4.webm' type='video/webm'/></video>

    <video id='myVideo' class='index_1' width='70%'' muted autoplay> 
    <source src='publicidad/video5.webm' type='video/webm'/></video>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot!

Braian

Comment: Post some code please

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob Pastebin isn't "some random link." However, relevant code should be included in the question itself.

Comment: This is my code: http://pastebin.com/ZJaHsupF can you see it now? Thank you very much :)